# SQL Query Returning Wring values for Sum and Count

Tags: mysql, sql

My SQL Query contains three tables the posts table, post_likes table, and comments table.
All tables are connected with the post_id primary key in the posts table. I am trying to return the content of the posts row as well the amount of likes/dislikes it has in the post_likes table, and the amount of comments. The query worked fine until I introduced the second left join and it now displays the like_count column x5 dislike_count column x5 and the new comment_count x4.

This is the query in question:

```
SELECT c.post_id, c.post_name, c.post_content, c.post_datetime, c.user_name, sum(p.like_count) AS like_count, sum(p.dislike_count) AS dislike_count, sum(s.comment_count) AS comment_count FROM posts c LEFT JOIN post_likes p ON c.post_id = p.post_id LEFT JOIN comments s ON c.post_id = s.post_id WHERE c.user_name = 'test' GROUP BY c.post_id
```

is returning the sum values:

```
//column | returned value | expected value

    like_count | 10 | 2
    dislike_count | 5 | 1
    comment_count | 20 | 5
```

Some additional notes, the likes/dislikes are stored in the postlikes table with the structure.

```
post_like_id, like_count, dislike_count, post_id, user_name
```

The like or dislike count can only be 1 in either column the PHP handles this to ensure users cant like multiple times etc and the user_name column is the user who liked the post.

The comments table structure is as follows:

```
comment_id, comment_name, comment_content, comment_datetime, comment_count, post_id, user_name
```

The comment_count is always 1 when inserted to allow for the sum function, post_id is the id of the post for the comment, and the user_name is the user who commented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `joins` are producing a cartesian product -- instead move the aggregation results into subqueries:

```
SELECT c.post_id, c.post_name, c.post_content, c.post_datetime, c.user_name, 
    p.like_count, 
    p.dislike_count, 
    s.comment_count
FROM posts c 
    LEFT JOIN (
       select post_id, 
              sum(like_count) like_count,
              sum(dislike_count) dislike_count
       from post_likes
       group by post_id
    ) p ON c.post_id = p.post_id 
    LEFT JOIN (
       select post_id, sum(comment_count) comment_count
       from comments
       group by post_id
    ) s ON c.post_id = s.post_id 
WHERE c.user_name = 'test'
```

Comment: Perfect this works right off the bat, I did not know you can use subqueries inside of a join +1. Thanks!

Comment: When I try to add COALESCE(sum(comment_count),0) it does not return 0 but returns the correct result for the posts with comments ? Any ideas

Comment: Sorry forgot to tag you above @sgeddes